# Initiate a job when scheduled event time matches with current time in FullCalendar using angular?

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I want to send a notification mail when scheduled event time matches with current time.
Is there a way to trigger some jobs automatically when the event time matches with current time in FullCalendar .

I am not able to find any solution .

Comment: Could you add more specifications? What do you call `time`? Is is the day? The exact date?

Comment: This sounds like a backend job, not front end. Use a cron job to check regularly for events in your database whose time  match the current date/time

Comment: Yes , like a event has been scheduled at this day and at this time .. So before starting of an  event a notification to be sent to the users via mail .

Comment: Ok well, like I said, that's what a cron job is for. Run the job at regular intervals, have it search your database for any events which are starting soon (you can define "soon" as whatever timescale yo need) and make it send an email for the event (or events) it finds. That has nothing to do with fullcalendar or angular - those are just tools you are using to show the event data to the end-users. They don't store the data, and they can't run automatically.

Comment: Thanks ADyson , I will configure in the backend .